# I am trying to extract nested list. Am I coding wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am trying to extract nested list. Am I coding wrong?

```py
l2=[3,4,5,6,7, [23,456,67,8,78,78], [345,56,87,8,98,9], (234,6657,6), {'key1': "sudh",234:[23,45,656]}]

for i in l2:
    if i==list:
        break

print (l2[i])
```

--------------------Out Put-----------------------

```
{'key1': "sudh",234:[23,45,656]}
```

Comment: Add expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please add expected output in your question**
As mentioned in question you need to check `type` and not it's value you can do as mentioned below:

```py
l2=[3,4,5,6,7, [23,456,67,8,78,78], [345,56,87,8,98,9], (234,6657,6), {'key1': "sudh",234:[23,45,656]}]

for i in l2:
    if type(i)==list:
        print(i)
# OR
for i in l2:
    if isinstance(i,list):
        print(i)
```

Output:

```
[23, 456, 67, 8, 78, 78]
[345, 56, 87, 8, 98, 9]
```

PS: `for i in l2` is iterating over it's element and it's not some index so you cannot use it as index in `l2[i]` as `i` is the element and not `index`

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining it so nicely.